# Chain android permission for bluetooth,location,background

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, android-permissions

I'm trying to chain my Android permissions. What I'm attempting to achieve is to check if the permissions are granted when the user focuses on a specific screen. First, by checking my Bluetooth; if it's false, then a Bluetooth modal will pop up with two options: cancel (to navigate back) and grant (to give permission). After that, I need to check the fine and coarse location permissions (same logic as the Bluetooth modal). Finally, I need to check the background permissions.

My current problem is that the location modal pops up before the Bluetooth modal, and the background permission modal doesn't appear at all.

```js
      useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      PermissionsAndroid.check(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
      ).then((res) => {
        console.log({ res });
        if (!res) {
          setBluetoothModal(true);
        }
        PermissionsAndroid.check(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ).then((res) => {
          res
            ? PermissionsAndroid.check(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
              ).then((res) => {
                res
                  ? PermissionsAndroid.check(
                      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                    ).then((res) => {
                      if (!res) {
                        PermissionsAndroid.request(
                          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS
                            .ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                          {
                            title: "Background Location Access",
                            message: `Darefore app collects location data in the background to record a session with GPS tracking on the phone. To record a session with GPS tracking, go to phone's Location permission and choose "Allow all the time".`,
                            buttonNegative: "Cancel",
                            buttonPositive: "OK",
                          }
                        );
                      }
                    })
                  : setLocationModal(true);
              })
            : setLocationModal(true);
        });
      });

      return () => {};
    }, [])
  );
```